# Issues with worker_threads in Node.js: Inconsistent Promise Execution Inside Workers

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, node-worker-threads

The issue I'm facing is that it seems the Worker doesn't always allow for the full execution flow of promises within it. Intriguingly, this happens quite randomly.

1. Connect to the database.
2. Perform various operations (e.g., queries, updates).
3. Disconnect from the database.

```js
const { parentPort, workerData } = require('node:worker_threads');
const Db = require('./path_to_database_helper');

parentPort.on('message', async (task) => {
    try {
        await Db.connect();

        // Several intermediary operations take place here.
        // Sometimes, they don't complete as intended.

        // Sometimes DB disconnect other no... 
        await Db.disconnect();
        
        // I always receive this message with DB connected or disconnected.
        // Is like the code jump into here always without completing the other tasks...
        parentPort.postMessage({ result: "some data" });

    } catch (error) {
        // Even if there's an error, I always reach the postMessage.
        await Db.disconnect();
        parentPort.postMessage({ error });
    }
});
```

To recap: the promises inside the worker don't consistently complete, but the postMessage always fires, which makes this behavior hard to pin down.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have insights into what might be causing this sporadic behavior? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**What did I try?**

I've thoroughly commented out almost all my code, leaving just a basic flow to monitor the database connection and disconnection process. When running inside a Docker container, the flow seems to work decently well, with only rare instances where it hangs and fails to disconnect. However, on AWS, the inconsistency magnifies. There are numerous times when the execution flow seems to jump ahead, the Worker closes, but processes like the database disconnection aren't completed.